# How can I track if one or more CheckBoxes in a group has been checked using useState hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

- "react": ">=16.14.0",
- "react-dom": ">=16.14.0"
- "@material-ui/core": "4.11.1",
- "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
- "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.53",
- "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
- "@material-ui/styles": "4.11.1",

Here is an example of one CheckBox that toggles `selected` and displays an error if it is unchecked.

**One CheckBox**

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false); 
const handleOnChange = (event) => setSelected(!selected);

<CheckBoxGroup error={!selected && 'You have to choose one!'} name="color" onChange={handleOnChange} label="Chose one" row>
  <CheckBox label="1" />
</CheckBoxGroup>;
```

And here's the same one with more than one CheckBox. I understand that I need to update my `handleOnChange` function where I could perhaps use `.find` to see if any CheckBox is ticked to return `true` but I can't figure out what to pass to the function i.e. how do I access to array of CheckBoxes?

**More than one CheckBox**

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false); 
const handleOnChange = (event) => setSelected(!selected);

<CheckBoxGroup error={!selected && 'You have to choose one!'} name="color" onChange={handleOnChange} label="Chose one" row>
  <CheckBox label="1" />
  <CheckBox label="2" />
  <CheckBox label="3" />
</CheckBoxGroup>;
```

Comment: What react library are you using?

Comment: Sorry, "react": ">=16.14.0", "react-dom": ">=16.14.0".

Comment: will only one checkbox be selected at any point of time

Comment: No, I meant what react library are you using for your `CheckBoxGroup`?

Comment: "@material-ui/core": "4.11.1", "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1", "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.53", "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10", "@material-ui/styles": "4.11.1",

Comment: Material UI doesn't seem to have a component called `CheckBoxGroup`. Did you implement it yourself? If so, how is the `onChange` prop implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should give your `<CheckBox>` components a `name` prop and an `onChange`. Then create an initial state for the checkboxes and pass that when initializing the state. In the `change` handler, we set the state for each checkbox according to the corresponding `name` and `checked` value. Set the `<CheckBox>`'s `checked` prop equal to the corresponding state value.

```js
export default function App() {
  // create an initial value for checkboxes
  const initialStatus = {
    first: false,
    second: false,
    third: false
  }

  // initialize a state variable to keep track of status
  const [checkboxStatus, setCheckboxStatus] = useState(initialStatus);
  
  // handle change event of checkboxes
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default action
    setCheckboxStatus({
      ...checkboxStatus,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.checked
    })
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CheckBox label="1" name="first" onChange={handleChange} checked={checkboxStatus.first} />
      <CheckBox label="2" name="second" onChange={handleChange} checked={checkboxStatus.second} />
      <CheckBox label="3" name="third" onChange={handleChange} checked={checkboxStatus.third} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but you've removed the `CheckBoxGroup` that tests the status of `checkboxStatus` and shows an error if no checkboxes are ticked.

Comment: I haven't worked with `CheckBoxGroup` in a while, but I think you can just put the checkboxes in for the same result.

Comment: Is the checkboxgroup a MUI component?

Comment: It is with some wrappers. Thanks for your answer, it put me on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of work and thanks to @axtck for his answer that made me look at the problem from a different angle.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { CheckBox, CheckBoxGroup } from '@globalization-partners/ui-components';

const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]); 
const handleOnChange = (event) => setSelected(event.target.checked ? [...selected, event.target.value] : selected.filter((data) => data !== event.target.value));

<CheckBoxGroup error={selected.length === 0 && 'You have to choose one!'} onChange={handleOnChange} label="Chose one" row>
  <CheckBox value='First' label='First' />
  <CheckBox value='Second' label='Second' />
  <CheckBox value='Third' label='Third' />
</CheckBoxGroup>;
```